# Populating column values from another table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables with the column as per below :

```
1) map(creativeid (integer), campaignid integer))

2) campaigns(id (integer), last_edited (date))

3) creatives(id(integer), last_edited (date))
```

**map** table maps creativeid with campaignid, both being foreign keys referenced from creatives and campaigns table respectively.

**Note**: One campaign item can contain multiple creatives

So currently I have entire data in **last_edited** column of **campaigns** table.
So I want to populate the data from campaigns last_edited column to the creatives last_edited column

Is there a way to acheive this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
update creatives
set last_edited = s.last_edited
from (
    select distinct on (m.creativeid, m.campaignid)
        m.creativeid, m.campaignid, ca.last_edited
    from
        campaigns ca 
        inner join
        map m on m.campaignid = ca.id
        inner join
        creatives cr on m.creativeid = cr.id
    order by 1, 2, 3 desc
) s
where id = s.creativeid
```

Comment: Its working but i would want to update the result into creatives last_modified column  @Clodoaldo Neto

Comment: @sForSujit Updated